# Jquery cookie for href attribute

Tags: jquery, events, cookies, append

I have a script which allows to save text with Jquery cookie plugin:[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gd5rX/1/)

As you can see the text of div(.jq-text) is being saved as a result of an event

```
$('.fields a').click(function(e){
          var text = $('#inputBox').val();
    ...
```

In the same event Im appending a link like this:

```
$('<a href="' + text + '">' + text + '</a>').appendTo('.jq-text');
```

Now the problem is that the text is being saved(refresh the page) but the link is not. So how is this possible, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: there is a 403 error when the browser request the jquery.cookie plugin, dude

Comment: You're fiddle does'nt work, but did you try doing this the simple way, like [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gd5rX/3/) ??

Comment: People my fiddle works, it stores the text but not the link(which is the problem) Please read the question before making comment

Comment: If you open the console (F12), you'll see that the cookie plugin is returning a 403, so your fiddle does NOT work.

Comment: I also tried this http://jsfiddle.net/gd5rX/4/ Which also doesnt seem to work

Comment: you are dynamically appending a node to the DOM with javascript, once you refreshed the page there will be no such node in the document. So the result you are getting is obvious.

Comment: @so geek Did you see my update  jsfiddle.net/gd5rX/4 Or is this the same case??

Comment: of course, whatever you are adding dynamically `href` in this case will be no more once u refreshed.

Comment: @so geek  So I guess the only way it will work is to first append/create dynamically and then have a second event to store the dynamically created link (???)

Comment: your jsfiddle gave me `{"error": "Please use POST request"}`

Comment: @Snake Eyes Thats weird..did you include the cookie plugin (which I added as recourse?

Comment: @Snake Eyes Im using Chrome and everything works on this side...dont now what youre getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try the following, but there may be better ways instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cookie = $.cookie('demoCookie');

    // If the cookie has been set in a previous page load, show it in the div directly:
    if (cookie){
        $('.jq-text').text(cookie).show();
        $('.jq-text').attr('href', cookie);
    }

    $('.fields a').click(function(e) {
        var text = $('#inputBox').val();

        // Setting a cookie with a seven day validity:
        $.cookie('demoCookie', text, {
            expires: 7,
            path: '/'
        });
        $('.jq-text').text(text).slideDown('slow');
        $('.jq-text').attr('href', text);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#form1').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});​
```

Look at the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thujeevan/gd5rX/5/)

Comment: Thanks for sticking around. Please not that the problem is "saving the href attribute" So I know how to save text, which is what your code is doing. For instance if you would type www.youtube.com It will not store the link. Instead it will store this: `<a class="jq-text" style="" href="#">www.youtube.com</a>` So the href = # So Im back from where I started..

Comment: So you are storing this: `$('.jq-text').attr('href', "#");` Instead of this: `$('.jq-text').attr('href', "www.youtube.com");`

Comment: I suppose it should be a var: `$('.jq-text').attr('href', SomeVar);` But I dont know how to put it all together

Comment: @Youss exactly, replace the `"#"` with `cookie` with a small change, look at my edit

Comment: Thank you very much:) Its not perfect (it doesn't go to youtube.com if clicked on link) but I can work with this.

Comment: @Youss to do that, type `http://www.youtube.com` in the input field, anyway you are welcome, but some websites refuse to load